# What do the memory section flags for a linker actually affect?

Tags: memory, linker

In a linker script, when defining memory sections, it's possible to specify certain flags:

```
MEMORY
{
    rom (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 0x100000
    ram (!rx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1C000
}
```

Looking at some online documentation for LD, it states:

> an optional list of attributes, permitted for compatibility with the AT&T linker but not used by ld beyond checking that the attribute list is valid

(Note that the above quote came from a positively ancient set of documentation for LD, circa 1994.)

Up-to-date binutils documentation indicates that (at least for GNU ld) these flags are used for automatically choosing memory segments for unassigned sections:

> The attr string is an optional list of attributes that specify whether to use a particular memory region for an input section which is not explicitly mapped in the linker script. As described in SECTIONS, if you do not specify an output section for some input section, the linker will create an output section with the same name as the input section. If you define region attributes, the linker will use them to select the memory region for the output section that it creates.

My question is, do these flags have any actual effects beyond the memory layout? Do they affect memory protection attributes at runtime? Are they useful if one specifically assigns each section to a memory segment?

Comment: Here is the linker flags and their usage. pg. 66 https://www.eecs.umich.edu/courses/eecs373/readings/Linker.pdf